# Prevent right/left arrow navigation in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 selects that I am enabling keyboard navigation(right and left arrow keys) to move between them. The default behavior when pressing the right or left arrow key is to move up/down the list.

My solution works moving between the selects, but every time you move to a new select, the selected value in the select that you just moved from gets moved up or down depending on which arrow you pressed.

Is there a way to prevent the default right and left arrow keys for the selects? I have tried e.preventPropagation and e.preventDefault but that doesn't seem to work.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/flynfish/emkqh/)

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: mojarra is not defined`, since you are using jQuery, just use `blur()` and **do not** use inline javascript..

Comment: @Neal That mojarra inline was leftover, I have removed it. The question still stands though.

Comment: I actually figured it out. I was binding to keypress rather then keydown. I will repost this comment as the answer in 7 hours. [JSFIDDLE SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/flynfish/emkqh/16/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. I was binding to keypress event, when I needed to bind to the keydown event. When binding to keydown then you can use e.preventDefault().

[JSFIDDLE SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/flynfish/emkqh/16/)

Comment: you are right, if I have some time I will play around with it.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK [see my workaround below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31206906/1185136).

Answer (score 1):

Since [OP's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7995076/1185136) does not work in Firefox, I created a workaround for the [known bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=291082).
Basically `event.preventDefault` doesn't prevent <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> on `<select>` nodes in Firefox.

[So here's the workaround in action](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly18vLz4/).

For more information on this, see [my detailed answer on similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31206759/1185136)

Answer (score 1):

No way to get it work in Firefox preventing event default.... And  Ruud solution is too complicated. So I've implemented that simple and clean solution, based on the same idea:

```
$('select').on('keydown', function( e ){
    switch(e.keyCode) { 
       // User pressed "left" or "right" arrow
       case 37:
       case 39:
           var val = $(this).val();
           var $slt = $(this).one('change', function(){
               $slt.val( val ).change();
           });
       break;
    }
});
```

The only inconvenient is that "change" event is triggered twice, so you're app may take care about that.