# jQuery - Using arrow keys when navigating away from select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below jQuery is what I am using to navigate through input elements on a jQDialog booking docket. I've added a class called `move` to each element I want it to navigate through.

One problem I am having is that when I navigate away from a `select` option it moves away from it on key down but changes the select option to the next value. Is there a way to disable this?

The other issue I'm having is that when going through the `move` classes, it doesn't appear to do this in the order I was expecting (it's not the same order as the tab, shift + tab keys)

**jQuery**

```
$(function  (){
    var keyUp = 38;
    var keyDown = 40;

    $(document).keydown(
        function(e)
        {
            var moves = $(".move");
            // Key up function
            if (e.keyCode == keyDown) {
                for(i = 0; i <= moves.length; i++) {
                    if (moves[i] == $(".move:focus").get(0)) {
                       $(moves[i + 1]).focus();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (e.keyCode == keyUp) {
                for(i = 0; i <= moves.length; i++) {
                    if (moves[i] == $(".move:focus").get(0)) {
                       $(moves[i - 1]).focus();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

**Select HTML example:**

```
                <select id="txt-payment" class="input-select move right" />

                  <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
                  <option value="Acc">Acc</option>
                  <option value="CC">CC</option>
                  <option value="PP">PP</option>

                </select>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It wouldn't be a good UX practice to change such behaviour. The users would be expecting to use the up/down arrows to navigate and change the selected items.

Comment: See this solution, maybe it help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7995076/1286937](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7995076/1286937)

Comment: Unfortunately that solutions doesn't work in Firefox, thanks anyway. I know it's not normal behavior, I tried to explain this, but it's just the way he is wanting it to work unfortunately.

Comment: Your markup has an issue. Remove the `/` from your `select` tag.

Comment: Some people request things and that's how they want it. I told him to use shift / shift + tab key but they don't want this. They don't seem to be bothered about bad practices as long as it functions

Comment: Thanks @MelanciaUK, the problem is that now I can't navigate away from the select box without pressing tab, the up and down keys just change the select option, the option needs to be changed by pressing a character, then up and down to navigate away from it

Comment: I've deleted my answer because there are some related questions on SO already, and none of them have a definitive answer. Most of the solutions would work on Chrome but not on FF or IE.